# Get request using Unirest to get a JSON stream

Tags: java, json, unirest

I am trying to establish this GET request:

```
 http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol=krakenUSD&start=1303100000
```

When I do this using postman, it works out perfectly. However, when I do this using an HttpRequest the body of the request returns as a null object.

```
            HttpRequest r = Unirest.get("http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv").queryString("symbol", "krakenUSD").queryString("start", "1303100000");
            System.out.println(r.getUrl());
            System.out.println(r.getBody().toString());
```

I get a null pointer error at:

```
 System.out.println(r.getBody().toString());
```

What is the proper way to submit this GET request? I am not sure if queryString() is what I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the request you are making might not return JSON. Look at the endpoint URL:

> "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv"

It most likely returns CSV, not JSON.

If the content type is 'application/json' or the URL is *.json, you have to invoke the .asJson method:

```
Unirest.post(URL)
  .queryString("symbol", "krakenUSD")
  .queryString("start", "1303100000")
  .asJson()
```

Reference: http://unirest.io/java.html